# cassandra disk space usage

Tags: garbage-collection, cassandra

The problem: Our cassandra's database occupies a lot of disc space. The estimated data size is about 10 Gb while disc space occupied is about 100Gb. We do a lot of writes/deletes. We have two nodes.

Here's what we tried to do (in the order it was done):

1. Run compaction on both nodes - completed, but zero effect
2. Set gc_grace to 0.
3. Run repair on both nodes - one node succeeded, on the other repair 'hang up' - it was alive, but lasted 3 days, after which we cut it off.
4. Run compaction on both nodes - completed, but still zero effect.

Can someone help with this? What should we do next? :)

Comment: which version of casssandra are you using? how are you loading data into cassandra? how much delete operations are you doing? have you tried running compaction twice after deleting data from cassandra with zero gc_grace?

Comment: - we use cassandra v1.1.2
- we use hector client like this (see in answer below)
- we do about 200 saves/min and 200 deletes/min of binary docs with average size of 2mb
- we did not delete with gc_grace=0. We deleted them first, then set gc_grace to 0, ran repair (1 of 2 nodes succeeded) and ran compaction.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem with Cassandra 2.0.9.

I succeeded in clearing space on HDD by using `nodetool clearsnapshot` on every node. It is possible to remove snapshots only for specified column families. Details on nodetool utility usage could be found [here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/tools/toolsNodetool_r.html).